# How to take Craigslist listings and put them on my website?

Tags: php, javascript, craigslist

How can I take Craigslist listings from a certain section of the page and put them on my website automatically as the Craiglist listings update? So when someone adds a listing on craigslist, it automatically gets put onto my site?

How would I do this using php and javascript? I am trying to integrate content from various websites to make it convenient for users.

Comment: Be careful, that sounds like a no no. Just a gut feeling. Maybe depends on what sites you are pulling data from?

Comment: It's not completely prohibited but limited: See chapter 12 in http://www.craigslist.org/about/terms.of.use

Comment: The best approach would be to contact them to see if they have any documentation for a public API.  If they have no public API, ask if they're willing to have a business relationship with you to expose an API of some sort for you to use.  If they're not willing to, you're out of luck.

Comment: They have an RSS feed! WTF are you guys talking about. Thats exactly what an RSS feed is for and what it stands for. Here, for developers who, somehow, don't know what RSS is for: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_syndication And if I could, i'd unclose this as this is a completely legit question with a fairly straightforward answer. TO THE POSTER, if you repost this let me know. I suggest asking "How do I pull in an RSS feed from an external site."

Comment: To the OP, also, you can't use JavaScript as you cant make cross server requests with JS, but you can use PHP since RSS is basically just XML. Here is a script you could use: http://www.weberdev.com/get_example-3820.html

Comment: @Oscar: The "put on my site" bit is and infringement of Craigslist Terms of use.

Comment: No, no it is not. How do you think CL apps are made? Christ. Also, if you read the TOS it says "craigslist permits you to display on your website, or create a hyperlink on your website to, individual postings on the Service" in CH12.P2.S1. If that were true, places like Google Reader would be in violation.

Comment: @Oscar:  craigslist grants you a limited, revocable, nonexclusive license to access 
the Service for your own personal use.  This license does not include: 
(a) access to the Service by Posting Agents; or (b) any collection, 
aggregation, copying, duplication, display or derivative use of the Service 
nor any use of data mining, robots, spiders, or similar data gathering and 
extraction tools for any purpose unless expressly permitted by craigslist.

Comment: @Oscar: craigslist permits you to display on your website, or create a hyperlink 
on your website to, individual postings on the Service so long as such use 
is for noncommercial and/or news reporting purposes only (e.g., for use in 
personal web blogs or personal online media).  If the total number of such 
postings displayed or linked to on your website exceeds one hundred (100) 
postings, your use will be presumed to be in violation of the TOU, 
absent express permission granted by craigslist to do so.

Comment: How do you know how he wants to use this information? How do you know its NOT his personal site and that he is going to use it against the TOS? Also, they just want links back. for example: http://www.housingmaps.com/ -- obv. gets WAY more than 100 postings but they link back and thats why they dont care. All CL is worried about is sites duplicating content JUST for SEO + adsense money. I think saying it's against the TOS completely is a complete misunderstanding and a departure from the intended use OF the TOS which is what you originally said.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you would be able to. I would assume you would need access to their SQL databases, and since they don't offer a free addon that would provide this functionality I really doubt you could.